# Foreach & FOR loop efficiency vs if-else

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, foreach, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D, I'm getting better performance when using if-else inside nested foreach (similarly nested FOR), instead of having a 3rd level nested foreach inside.

The problem is that I thought writing the code, as shown below was not the correct and/or optimized way of writing code.

```
        foreach(GameObject element in all_elements_on_screen) 
        {
          foreach(Transform child in element.transform) 
          {

            if (child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileA || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileB ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileC || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileD ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileE || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileF ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileG || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileH ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileI || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileJ ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileK || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileL ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileM || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileN ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileO || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileP ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileQ || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileR ||
              child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileS || child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == TileT) {
              Destroy(child.GetComponent < PolygonCollider2D > ());

            } 

            else

            {
              child.gameObject.AddComponent < PolygonCollider2D > ();

            }
          }
        }
```

Therefore, I tidied (made it more optimized?) the code by creating another nested foreach loop:

```
    foreach(GameObject element in all_elements_on_screen) 
    {
      foreach(Transform child in element.transform) 
      {

        foreach(Sprite crater_texture in textures_craters) 
        {
          if (child.GetComponent < SpriteRenderer > ().sprite == crater_texture) 
          {
            Destroy(child.GetComponent < PolygonCollider2D > ());
          } 
          else 
          {
            child.gameObject.AddComponent < PolygonCollider2D > ();
          }
        }
      }

    }
```

Both of these snippets do the exact same thing, EXCEPT the latter piece of code takes more time to load/run than the former. Why is that happening? is there any other way of optimizing this piece of code so it runs faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you provided are not equal. The first checks the equality and calls either `Destroy()` or `AddComponent` *once*. The latter calls one or the other *many times*, since it's inside the foreach loop.

What type is the `textures_crater`? Could you rather check if `crater_texture` is in the array/list/whatever using default methods and then decide what to do?

For example, if it is a List, you could do:

```
foreach(GameObject element in all_elements_on_screen) 
{
  foreach(Transform child in element.transform) 
  {
    if (textures_craters.Contains(child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite)
    {
      Destroy(child.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>());
    } 
    else 
    {
      child.gameObject.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    }
  }
}
```

If, for some reason, the `textures_craters` is some strange container you cannot use this kind of Contains method, you can always use a helper boolean, loop through it and determine if the element is in the container, and afterwards call one or the other method accordingly.

Comment: Works like a charm! Optimized and short. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second case forces an iteration for *every* item in textures_craters.  The first case only runs through your conditions until it has encountered one true condition and then it can stop, because `||` short-circuits (`||` is true as soon as one sub-condition is true).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes complete sense. Both FOR and FOREACH forces the iteration to finish, that's why the time to process the entire LIST takes longer. So, does that mean it's considered okay for programmers to do something like what I've done in the first example? It doesn't look very optimized.

Comment: I think you could optimize further by having a pre-fabricated Array of your TileA-TileT Sprites and binary searching if the sprite you have is in that array.  I'll post some code along those lines as an update.  However, I don't know what TileA, etc. is.  Is TileA a variable or constant you have elsewhere?  Or is it Type?  (Not so familiar with the specifics of Unity).

Comment: TileA, TileB and so on.. are all Sprites. @Sami answered the question. His code works very well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've updated with a BinarySearch that has potential to be faster than your large if condition.

Comment: Added some info on the Contains vs. BinarySearch.  However, unless you need this thing to have screaming fast performance you are fine with Contains.

Comment: `Sprite` does not implement `IComparable`, so you can't use binary search.

Comment: @StefanHoffmann, I've added an example SpriteComparer that implements IComparer

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear. To benefit from a binary search the array must already be sorted by some rule. If you're using binary search on an unsorted array it may not even find an existing element in the array. Unlike numbers, sprites (images) have no natural ordering. *Maybe* the sprites can be sorted by their name property, if they are named like `TileA`, `TileB`, etc. In the end, it may not be worth the effort compared to the simple search with `Contains` :)

Comment: @StefanHoffmann: You are right. Going to delete the stuff about BinarySearch.

Comment: I deleted the stuff I had added on BinarySearch.  My mistake was in nto thinking through that a Binarysearch  needs a rigorous notion of less, equal, greater in order for the array to be sorted and for the search to be effective. The IComparer I provided couldn't do that--it could tell if items were equal or not, but had no concept of less or greater, thus defeating the idea of a Binarysearch.